# node.js Https call return undefined. Amazon AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am completely new to node.js but have the following code, which I have written mostly with cut & paste. It is running in Amazon AWS, responding to an Alexa call. I am trying to read a thingspeak channel to get the temperature in my pool. The URL returns a json with temperature. The channel is updated by an esp8266 which is measuring the pooltemp and posts it to the channel.

Unfortunately I am only getting undefined pooltemp.  I create the function getCall() to get the temperature from thingspeak. When I use the variable pooltemp in handlerinput it is undefined. Everything else work fine. If I hardcode pooltemp in handlerinput I get the response I want.

It now works like this: First time running the pooltemp is undefined. If run one more time immediately I get pooltemp = 30 (which is the new temp). That at least says that the call to thingspeak is working. If I run it again after a few minutes it is again undefined first time. Seems that AWS keeps the value for a while after the function finish.

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');

var https = require('https');
var pooltemp;

  getCall();

//ThingSpeak Data Access

function getCall() {
  var options = {
    protocol: 'https:', 
    host: 'api.thingspeak.com',
    path: '/channels/494722/feeds.json?api_key=9HILOGJ9P2HRDPNO&results=1',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var getReq = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("\nstatus code: ", res.statusCode);
    var jsonData = '';
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        jsonData += data;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('We have all the data');
      var result = JSON.parse(jsonData);
      console.log('data: ', result);
      console.log('Pool temperature: ', result.feeds[0].field1);
      // Save the latest pool temperature.
      pooltemp = result.feeds[0].field1;
    });
  });

  //end the request
  getReq.end();
  getReq.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  });
}


const GetNewFactHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'LaunchRequest' ||
      (request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
        request.intent.name === 'GetNewFactIntent');
  },
  
  
  
  handle(handlerInput) {

 
    //  var pooltemp = 22;
    var factIndex;
    const factArr = data;
    if (pooltemp <= 15) {
      factIndex = 0;
    }
    if (15 < pooltemp == pooltemp < 20) {
      factIndex = 1;
    }
    if (20 <= pooltemp == pooltemp < 25) {
      factIndex = 2;
    }
    if (pooltemp >= 25) {
      factIndex = 3;
    }
   
   
    const randomFact = factArr[factIndex];
    const speechOutput = 'Hold on a second, I will check for you.<break time="1s"/>Today it is ' + pooltemp + ' degrees in the pool. ' + randomFact;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, randomFact)
      .getResponse();
    
  },
};

const HelpHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(HELP_MESSAGE)
      .reprompt(HELP_REPROMPT)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const ExitHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent' ||
        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(STOP_MESSAGE)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};

const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, an error occurred.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, an error occurred.')
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SKILL_NAME = 'Space Facts';
const GET_FACT_MESSAGE = 'Here\'s today temperature: ';
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me a space fact, or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';

const data = [
  'It is freezing cold. Swimming only for idiots',
  'It is not for wimps, but you may swim. Do you dare go for it?',
  'Which is a nice temperature for a Norwegian.',
  'This is quite comfortable and a swim should be really nice ',

];

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    GetNewFactHandler,
    HelpHandler,
    ExitHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this out and made a few modifications to the getCall() function, it should work now:

```
function getCall() {
  var options = {
    protocol: 'https:', 
    host: 'api.thingspeak.com',
    path: '/channels/494722/feeds.json?api_key=9HILOGJ9P2HRDPNO&results=1',
    method: 'GET'
  }

  var getReq = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("\nstatus code: ", res.statusCode);
    var jsonData = '';
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        jsonData += data;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
       console.log('We have all the data');
       var result = JSON.parse(jsonData);
       console.log('data: ', result);
       console.log('Pool temperature: ', result.feeds[0].field1);
       // Save the latest pool temperature.
       poolTemp = result.feeds[0].field1;
    });
  });

  //end the request
  getReq.end();
  getReq.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  });
}

getCall();
```

You could also try this at the start of your script:

```
getCall();
setInterval(getCall, 10000);
```

This would refresh the pool temperature every 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for for your answer and effort. I tried your solution but it still returns undefined.

Comment: Weird! it's the old works on my machine.. ;-) Node 6.9 Windows 7. Let me check on another platform!

Comment: Thank you. I am running it as  node.js in AWS lambda mode is 6.10. I can choose 4.3 and 8.10 but same problem

Comment: It's strange, I was getting 22 degrees for pool temp, does that sound right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Have you tested the hole code or just the function? Can it be that the function has not finished when I test for pooltemp?

Comment: I haven't tested the whole section of code, just the function above. I think you are correct, you may be trying to read pooltemp before it has returned.

Comment: I'd suggest making getCall return a Promise and you can do getCall ().then to continue execution. OR Just call getCall () on a timer, e.g setInterval (getCall, 10000); this way pooltemp will keep updating.

Comment: I've changed the code to save the pool temp in a slightly different way!

Comment: I have updated the code in my original post. It now works like this: FIrst time running the pooltemp is undefined. If run one more time immediately I get pooltemp = 30 (which is the new temp). That at least says that the call to thingspeak is working. If I run it again after a few minutes it is again undefined first time. Seems that AWS keeps the value for a while after the function finish. I can not use setinterval in AWS. The function is not constantly running. It only run once when called by amazon Alexa.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you function **getCall()** is executing asynchronously, So **pooltemp** is undefined. Because of javascript asynchrouns nature before the successful execution of **getCall()** function, it moves on to if condition

Here I made a changes in **getCall** function using javascript callback. Also in GetNewFactHandler **handle()** method after the successful execution of **getCall** function remaining conditions will be executed.

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');

var https = require('https');

//ThingSpeak Data Access
function getCall(callback) {
  //initialize options values, the value of the method can be changed to POST to make https post calls
  var options = {
    protocol: 'https:', 
    host: 'api.thingspeak.com',
    path: '/channels/494722/feeds.json?api_key=9HILOGJ9P2HRDPNO&results=1',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  //making the https get call
  https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("\nstatus code: ", res.statusCode);
    let data = ''

    // A chunk of data has been recieved from request stream.  
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    // Once the whole response has been received, return response as callback
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('We have all the data');
      var result = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log('data: ', result);
      console.log('Pool temperature: ', result.feeds[0].field1);
      // Save the latest pool temperature.
      const poolTemp = result.feeds[0].field1;
      callback(null, poolTemp);
    });
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });
}

const GetNewFactHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'LaunchRequest' ||
      (request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
        request.intent.name === 'GetNewFactIntent');
  },

  handle(handlerInput) {

    getCall((err, pooltemp) => {
        //Error handling implementation
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err);    
        }
        //Validating condition after successful response from getCall       
        //  var pooltemp = 22;
        var factIndex;
        const factArr = data;
        if (pooltemp <= 15) {
          factIndex = 0;
        }
        if (15 < pooltemp == pooltemp < 20) {
          factIndex = 1;
        }
        if (20 <= pooltemp == pooltemp < 25) {
          factIndex = 2;
        }
        if (pooltemp >= 25) {
          factIndex = 3;
        }

        const randomFact = factArr[factIndex];
        const speechOutput = 'Hold on a second, I will check for you.<break time="1s"/>Today it is ' + pooltemp + ' degrees in the pool. ' + randomFact;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechOutput)
          .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, randomFact)
          .getResponse();
    }
  },
};

const HelpHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(HELP_MESSAGE)
      .reprompt(HELP_REPROMPT)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const ExitHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent' ||
        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(STOP_MESSAGE)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};

const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, an error occurred.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, an error occurred.')
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SKILL_NAME = 'Space Facts';
const GET_FACT_MESSAGE = 'Here\'s today temperature: ';
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me a space fact, or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';

const data = [
  'It is freezing cold. Swimming only for idiots',
  'It is not for whimps, but you may swim. Do you dare go for it?',
  'Wich is a nice temperature for a norwegian.',
  'This is quite comfortable and a swim should be really nice ',

];

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    GetNewFactHandler,
    HelpHandler,
    ExitHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After correcitng the code something is still wrong. Now I only get the following error in Alexa skill kit: There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Comment: When I test it from the alexa skill console I  now get : an unexpected error occurred. Try again later. When I put the code back to original it runs as expected, besides the pooltemp is reported as undefined.

Comment: I have updated the code in my original post. It now works like this: FIrst time running the pooltemp is undefined. If run one more time immediately I get pooltemp = 30 (which is the new temp). That at least says that the call to thingspeak is working. If I run it again after a few minutes it is again undefined first time. Seems that AWS keeps the value for a while after the function finish. I can not use setinterval in AWS. The function is not constantly running. It only run once when called by amazon Alexa.

Comment: Due to asynchronous nature of Javascript first time you are getting response as undefined for getCall. Because before completion of the API call (http request to api.thingspeak.com) your if condition gets executed. Once the response came back from  api.thingspeak.com it is assigned to pooltemp. Thats why when you call second time yoiu are getting value in pooltemp. In order to make the javascript synchronous callbacks & promises were used. In sample callback methdology is used. I adivse you to get an good understanding on callback, promises.